# Parse CSV file to object manually with some computation in .net

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

I have huge CSV file around 300MB and I'm reading it by using a library called CsvHelper. Reading the whole file does not take too long. However, I have to parse it to an object manually instead of using automatic conversion. The reason is, I have to do some calculation based on each data.

For example,sometimes I need to combine 2 or more fields into 1 field to store them in the object. Or I need to check if the field is there and also the value is not null. If null, I need to do another calculation based on other fields.

I have also written my own code to read it line by line and convert header and rows to a list by separating them with comma. The plain reading time improved but parsing time was about the same. It takes like 30 minutes to parse whole to the object and I need to improve that. I haven't used any Parallel or similar stuff. It might help but I'd like know if there are other better options.

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: We can't help to improve code that is invisible. However, i doubt that the CPU is the bottleneck but the disk speed. You could try to read all into memory using `File.ReadAllLines`,  then [`Parallel.Foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx) could make a difference.